# Set overflow to visible in svg tag with raphael.js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm rendering a svg with raphael.js and than the value of "overflow" is hidden. I want to change this value to "visible", but it is not possible to change that with setAttribute. I wrote in my svg-file overflow="visible" but if raphael.js render the file, than overflow has the value "hidden". Is there a way to render the svg and than change the value of overflow?

Comment: If you can, please add the jsfiddle for it.